# C/C++ Cross-Platform Unicode Encoding

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding, cross-platform, arm

Is there a cross-platform way (in C/C++) to make from a unsigned char an unicode wchar_t (that can also handle different encodings/codepages as input)? I searching for something like `WideCharToMultiByte(...)` on W32. My target platform has ARM architecture, so I can't use this...

I would also be fine, with some library, if it's free & can run on an ARM platform...

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) is a free, open-source, cross-platform library for dealing with Unicode text and other globalization issues. It supports C, C++, and Java.